# SQL Query takes long time with parameter check

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query which is taking a really long time based on a parameter check....

The query it self is part of a stored procedure used for a search screen.  Basically you fill out a form with a whole lot of text/combo boxes to search from. I have multi-select combo boxes that will pass through multiple values for the same field in way of a delimited field.

The following is a cut down version of the query to illustrate my problem...

```
select
    o.id,
    o.createdBy 
into
    #results
from
    jmsTransOther o
where 
    o.(WorkOrderId IN (SELECT intValue FROM dbo.fn_SplitInts(@WorkOrderIds, ',')) <strong>OR @WorkOrderIds = ''</strong>)
```

I quite often use this parameter check `OR @WorkOrderIds = ''` which basically means if this is not true then perform the other side of the statement.

This works quite well in most cases but for some reason with this `fn_SplitInts` function which is basically converting the delimited list into a table and then performing a "IN" statement is taking a really long time.

This table has about 200,000 records in it - currently this takes around 40 seconds to search. However, if I remove the parameter check i.e. `OR @WorkOrderIds = ''`, then it takes less than a second.

I can work around it but just wanted to know what is going on here....?

Comment: This is almost definitely a parameter sniffing issue. The short solution is to  simply add `WITH RECOMPILE` to your stored procedure. I suggest you do some research on parameter sniffing in general though, just so you understand whats going on

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid ok didnt think of that.  I have had this issue before.  However, I am getting this same issue when just testing the query in a query window isolated by itself?  Does this now exclude it from a parameter sniffing issue??

Comment: No. Any client application (SSMS or a web app) can incur parameter sniffing

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - Your suggestion is correct.  If you post this as an answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Glad I could help. I might just post as a duplicate if thats OK

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest this formulation:

```
select o.id, o.createdBy 
into #results
from jmsTransOther o
where o.WorkOrderId IN (SELECT intValue FROM dbo.fn_SplitInts(@WorkOrderIds, ',')) 
union all
select o.id, o.createdBy 
from jmsTransOther o
where @WorkOrderIds = '';
```

The `or` is probably messing up the statistics.  (I would also use `NULL` rather than the empty string to mean "all of them".)

Comment: Unfortunately I have about 6 of these same parameter checks for different criteria in the where condition which would mean this solution would get quite messy...

Comment: @GlenHong . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you ask.  If you have another question, then ask it as a *new* question.  Editing this question will only server to invalidate this answer -- which can draw downvotes.

Comment: Well there is a question on the last line...I wasnt really looking so much for a solution as I can work around it.  I was more looking to some insight as to what was causing the issue....as Nick Mermaid has pointed out what he thinks is the problem